# How can We access 2 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjYRZ.png)

How can i access a data.mac . I tried many times `data[0].mac` And did many try but I am not getting How can I access this .

Thank You

How to access a single value in 2 dimensional array.

```
const data = [];
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var res = this.responseText;
    //console.log(res);

    res.split(']').forEach((el) => {
      if (!el) return;

      const [mac, ttl, time] = el.split(',');
      const obj = data.find(o => o.mac === mac);

      if (obj) {
        obj.ttl = ttl;
        obj.time = time;
      } else {
        data.push({
          mac,
          ttl,
          time
        });
      }
    });
  }
};


xhr.open("GET", "http://192.168.43.154/wifimac", true);
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Pls don't post images of code. See if you can copy and paste that code into your question (formatted) and show your attempt.

Comment: `data[0].mac` should work, of course if what you displayed on your screenshot is actually `data`. We can't know for sure because we don't see any code, or anything that prove that you are showing `data`

Comment: javascript doesn't really support 2D arrays. You can have arrays of arrays, which kind of act like a 2D array. You may need `data[0][0].mac` if you have two levels of indirection

Comment: This isn't a 2-dimensional array, it's an array of objects. Based on your image, there's no reason why `data[0].mac` shouldn't work, so you're probably not sharing enough details about your issue.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'mac')
    at script.js:174:25

console.log(data[0].mac);

Comment: I have updated a post with a code sorry

Comment: From [MDN(Array.prototype.find())](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

"The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function. If no values satisfy the testing function, undefined is returned." I think either your array is empty or none of the elements holds the condition you provided.

Comment: There is no part in the shown code where you have `data[0].mac`. Please show where you try to do `data[0].mac`.